Converting an annotation to an attribute: How to type optional TranslatableMarkup
I'm trying to create a PHP Attribute based on a Doctrine Annotation for a contrib module.
I'm confused about how to type $description, which is Translatable Markup but defaults to an empty string.
Here is the original annotation for $description:
  /**
   * The description shown to users.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation
   *
   * @ingroup plugin_translatable
   */
  public $description = '';

And here is the attribute I created:
#[\Attribute(\Attribute::TARGET_CLASS)]
class EncryptionMethod extends Plugin {

  /**
   * Constructs an EncryptionMethod.
   *
   * @param string $id
   *   The plugin ID.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup|string $description
   *   (optional) The description shown to users.
   */
  public function __construct(
    public readonly string $id,
    public readonly TranslatableMarkup|string $description = '',
  ) {}

What I wanted to do was to type $description as Translatable Markup, but then I can't set the default for $description to an empty string.
So I tried setting $description to new TranslatableMarkup(''), but this is a coding standards violation (do not call TranslatableMarkup with empty string).
I seem to be stuck because the annotation returns an empty string, and I have to keep the attribute compatible with the annotation.
How should I type the $description, which is an optional case of TranslatableMarkup?

This is how core's Block.php does it:
  /**
   * Constructs a Block attribute.
   *
   * @param string $id
   *   The plugin ID.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup|null $admin_label
   *   The administrative label of the block.

So I suggest updating the type of both the attribute and the annotation to be TranslatableMarkup|null.
